# Can i change data in a database using smart contract and oraclize?

Tags: oracles, database

i understand that smart contract and oraclize can be use to get data from a database but can i manipulate the data inside the database using smart contract and oraclize? If so how can i do it?

Can I use Oraclize to send HTTP POST response and through that use an API to update the existing database?

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can achieve such a thing via Oraclize!

First, you'll need to create and expose an API to perform the database duties you need.

Next, you'll need to use the Oraclize computation datasource in order to craft your POST requests and payload data they might need. It involves creating a docker container containing whatever code it is you need to run, which you then deploy to the `IPFS` network.

Once done, you can run this code via an Oraclize query, passing along any data you might need in order to update your database.

The [Oraclize Examples Repo here](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples) has a "URL-Requests" example [here](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/tree/e983db746ac76a6e4b0984c09f7b3c1c4deec262/solidity/computation-datasource/url-requests) that shows you how to do the above. There is also a [Truffle Version of the example here](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/tree/e983db746ac76a6e4b0984c09f7b3c1c4deec262/solidity/truffle-examples/url-requests), showing how you'd set it up in a development environment, with unit testing in place.